# Taxonomy term duplicates result

Tags: views, 7

[image]I have created nodes and added taxononmy

Under views i want taxonomy seperarte. it is showing

A, B, C, A , B

A, B , C are my taxnomy terms

i want A , B, C are in tabs  as a taxonomy

Any idea

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use Views to display your node and aggregate your Taxonomy terms to prevent duplicates.

Comment: Can you please explain how to aggregate to prevent duplicates

Comment: In your view, go to the last options "Other" and click "Use aggregation". Then all the fields added will have an aggregation option attached so you can decide which way you want or do not want them to be aggregated.

Comment: Still not working, i added a screen shoot in my question

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong about aggregation, you don't need it.

In your case, you might want to use the "Multiple field option" of your taxonomy field. Leave the "Display all values" box checked, and choose to display only one value.

And don't forget to group results by taxonomy in your format options.

This works fine for me.

Comment: i didn't get you. Can u pls little bit explain.

Comment: 1/ Click your term field, you should have a setting named "Multiple Field Settings"
2/ Leave everything as is, except the "Display" value. Change "all" to "1".
3/ In the format options, make sure your grouping field nr 1 is set to your taxonomy term

Comment: there is no option for multiple field settinhgs

Comment: Maybe this will help : https://www.ostraining.com/support-forum/drupal-support/missing-multiple-field-settings/